# Custom query in posts_search

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

How can I use this query as my custom search query?

```
add_filter('posts_search', 'my_search_is_perfect', 20, 2);
function my_search_is_perfect($search, $wp_query) 
{
   $sWord = 'Zukunft haus';

   return "
       SELECT *, 
              MATCH(post_title) AGAINST('$sWord' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS Score 
        FROM `wp_posts` 
       INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_term_relationships.object_id = ID
             AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = 1
       WHERE MATCH( post_title) AGAINST ('$sWord' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
         AND `post_status` = 'publish'
         AND `post_type` = 'post'
       ORDER BY score DESC
  "; 
}
```

The query is correct (I checked this in phpMyAdmin) but in WordPress I get the message, no results.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: The filter posts_search will only accept  WHERE Clausels for filter usage always check the core files:  https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/query.php#L2701

Comment: To execute a raw query, probably it's better to use `$wpdb` global directly. There is a complete reference about it in the WP documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: i don't understand why its down voted? in my opinion, if so its nice to comment explaining the reason why it was down voted.

Answer (score 5):

**In function.php file:**

```
add_filter('posts_search', 'my_search_is_perfect', 20, 2);
function my_search_is_perfect() 
{
    global $post;
    global $wpdb;
    $sWord = 'Zukunft haus';

    $sel_query = "SELECT *, 
                          MATCH(post_title) AGAINST('$sWord' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS Score 
                    FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."posts 
                   INNER JOIN ".$wpdb->prefix."term_relationships ON ".$wpdb->prefix."term_relationships.object_id = ID
                         AND ".$wpdb->prefix."term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = 1
                   WHERE MATCH( post_title) AGAINST ('$sWord' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
                     AND post_status = 'publish'
                     AND post_type = 'post'
                   ORDER BY score DESC";
    $totaldata = $wpdb->get_results($sel_query);

    return $totaldata;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Gustavo Straube, it would be better to use $wpdb in which case you should implement it like this:

```
add_filter('posts_search', 'my_search_is_perfect', 20, 2);

function my_search_is_perfect() 
{
    global $wpdb;

    $sWord = 'Zukunft haus';

    $query = "SELECT *, 
                  MATCH(post_title) AGAINST('$sWord' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS Score 
            FROM `".$wpdb->prefix."_posts` 
           INNER JOIN ".$wpdb->prefix."_term_relationships ON ".$wpdb->prefix."_term_relationships.object_id = ID
                 AND ".$wpdb->prefix."_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = 1
           WHERE MATCH( post_title) AGAINST ('$sWord' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
             AND `post_status` = 'publish'
             AND `post_type` = 'post'
           ORDER BY score DESC";

    $myrows = $wpdb->get_results( $query );

    return $myrows;
}
```

You can find more information in https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Answer (score 0):

Custom queries in wordpress are executed via $wpdb. If you use simply mysql query filters in wordpress may not execute the queries to avoid SQL injections. So use $wpdb to create custom queries.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your intention is to completely disregard WordPress' query and fetch posts using your own custom query. In this case `posts_search` is the wrong filter to use. The purpose of `posts_search` is for you to insert additional search clauses into the the `$search` parameter: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_search/

The correct filter to use to perform a customized posts fetch is `posts_pre_query`. It gives you the opportunity to fetch the posts and return them: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_pre_query/. A good example of this is [Paginating results from posts_pre_query - Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68565816/212076).

And here `posts_pre_query` is used to completely block fetching of posts: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/354103/657

The answer by @Juancho Ramone is perfect, only that the filter in use should be `posts_pre_query`:

```
function my_search_is_perfect($posts, &$query) 
{
    global $wpdb;

    $sWord = 'Zukunft haus';

    $query = "SELECT *, 
                  MATCH(post_title) AGAINST('$sWord' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS Score 
            FROM `".$wpdb->prefix."_posts` 
           INNER JOIN ".$wpdb->prefix."_term_relationships ON ".$wpdb->prefix."_term_relationships.object_id = ID
                 AND ".$wpdb->prefix."_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = 1
           WHERE MATCH( post_title) AGAINST ('$sWord' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
             AND `post_status` = 'publish'
             AND `post_type` = 'post'
           ORDER BY score DESC";

    $myrows = $wpdb->get_results( $query );

    return $myrows;
}
add_filter('posts_pre_query', 'my_search_is_perfect', 20, 2);
```