# Paginating results from posts_pre_query - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, search, filter

I have a function that gets posts based off of ids returned by an outside source. I use the `post_pre_query` filter to override wordpress's default functionality. This correctly returns the desired results, but pagination is a disaster. In the documentation for `post_pre_query` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_pre_query/ it says that `found_posts` and `max_num_pages` should be set in order to make pagination work, but that doesn't do the trick. Unfortunately example code for `post_pre_query` is relatively non-existent, which makes this tough. I've tried setting several other values such as `posts_per_page`, `paged`, and `is_paged`, but these don't alter the functionality at all. In fact, they are completely ignored.

Currently, the max pages is correct, but the same results are displayed on each page and they aren't clamped to the `posts_per_page` value.

Here is my filter function in its current state:

```
function default_search_override( $posts, &$query ) {
    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search) {
        $skus= get_exterior_skus($_GET['year'], $_GET['make'], $_GET['model'], $_GET['filter']);
        
        if(empty($skus)) return $posts;
        
        $posts = get_post_ids_from_skus($skus);
        //var_dump($posts);
        
        $posts_per_page = 6; //$query->query_vars['posts_per_page'];
        $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        echo sizeof($posts) . " / " . $posts_per_page . ".....";
        $query->max_num_pages = floor(sizeof($posts) / $posts_per_page);
        $query->posts_per_page = $posts_per_page;
        $query->found_posts = sizeof($posts);
        $query->paged = $paged;
        $query->is_paged = true;
        print_r($query);
        echo "_______";
        print_r($query->query_vars);
    }
    return $posts;
}
add_filter( 'posts_pre_query', 'default_search_override', 10, 2);
```

I am relatively new to wordpress and even more so with pagination, so perhaps this is a simple fix that I'm just missing.

I've researched serveral things about pagination such as using paginate_links, but I don't think that works for this since its not in the search template file.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution that worked for me, but may not work for everyone. The specific endpoint I'm getting my ids from has parameters for page and limit. So, with that, I can simply use limit to limit the result to whatever my `posts_per_page` value is. Then, I can set found posts to the count of that and `max_num_pages` to the count of the result without pages or limit, which my specific endpoint returns, which is convenient.

If anyone has an answer for paginating  purely from WordPress I'd still love to hear it, because I'm still at a loss on that end.